# Why is my check_password_hash returning false always python flask

Tags: python

```
if request.method == "POST":

     email = request.form['email']
     password = request.form['password']
     cursor=mysql.connect.cursor()
     row = cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM login WHERE email = %s',[email])
     if row>0:
       row2= cursor.execute('SELECT password FROM login WHERE email = %s', [email])
       row2 = cursor.fetchall()
       cursor.close()
       if check_password_hash(row2[0][0],password):
             return('index.html')
cursor.close()
```

Comment: Thanks but it does not entirely solve the problem

Comment: What prints if you print row2[0][0] before your if statement and does that match what prints if you print password?  Also why do you need the second cursor when you have both the password and email from the original query?

Comment: could you please include the code in check_password_hash? this is what decides if it returns True of False

Comment: row2[0][0]is the password for the particular user that has logged in